# write unit test for code that uses a pointer

Tags: c#, pointers, mstest

I'm trying to build out some testing in an already-developed application that our group is supporting. it's most in c#, though it uses some c++ dlls and some of the memory management was developed 'by hand'.  Please don't tell me about how to do memory management in c#...that code is written and it works, I'm just trying to write tests. SUT is .NET Standard 2.0, my test class (at this point) is .NET Framework 4.6.2, but I guess I could change that. EDIT: the project definitely has the 'Allow unsafe code' checkbox checked, both for the test project and the SUT.

Anyways, the SUT has an extension method and a property I need to use. one is:

`SUT.SourcePtr`, which provides a `void*` return
the other is 
`SUT.CopyFrom(void*)`, I think you can see where this is going.
Firstpass, I just wanted to have my test verify I can run something like the following, assuming both objects are properly instantiated:

`sut1.CopyFrom(sut2.SourcePtr);`
For obvious reasons, I need it to be:

```
unsafe
{
    sut1.CopyFrom(sut2.SourcePtr);
}
```

But when these lines are in the `[TestMethod]`, the test explorer won't run the test. It doesn't say it gets skipped, it just doesn't run it.  Test output says:

> [12/10/2018 12:19:51 PM Informational] Executing test method '..'
>   [12/10/2018 12:19:51 PM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>   [12/10/2018 12:19:57 PM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:05.5860315) ==========

BUT... If I make a separate testdeclared as `public unsafe void LoadSutUnsafe()`, it runs fine (first example is a `[DataTestMethod]` (but when I change the attribute on my new one, it doesn't change the behavior), if that makes a difference.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: My first thought is tests are not compiled with the /unsafe option, which causes the test to be ignored. If you could post complete code example, that might help.